# SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 link not available to download

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, service-pack

From where can I download SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 and RTM versions 14.0.4763.1000 build? From Microsoft Update site the link is not available.
Has Microsoft removed support of SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 and below?

My client is still running the SharePoint Server 2010 RC (Release Candidate) version and need to install RTM and then SP1.

But nowhere I can find SP1 or RTM link to download, even Microsoft office download SP1 link is breaking and while installing April CU (KB2512800) for SP Server 2010 it is throwing error - "The expected version of the product was not found on the system".

To install these CUs what is the minimum version of SharePoint Server 2010 my client should be running? RC is enough or it should be at least RTM?

Please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. The SP1 link is no longer available for download. You cannot upgrade from RC to RTM or SP1. They'll have to start off with a new farm and new data as it is also not supported to migrate the data from pre-RTM versions of SharePoint).

That said, you should be installing [SP2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39672). SP1 is no longer supported by Microsoft.

Microsoft only provides slipstreamed versions of SP2 for [SharePoint Foundation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24983). RTM of SharePoint Server 2010 is available on MSDN.